# Hypothesis testing & inherently skewed data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, repeated-measures, skewness, ordered-logit

I've run an experiment where I asked participants to indicate how they feel using a likert scale (1-7) in response to images they were being shown. The images were experimentally manipulated to (hopefully) alter how the viewers feel about them, and I'm looking to test if this is reflected in the likert ratings.

The issue I'm having is that some of the items that participants responded to on the likert scale yielded skewed data. The liked scales evaluated affective states, so participants were stating their agreement with affective dimensions such as "happy", "sad", and so on.

My analysis plan was to examine the self-report likert data using a repeated measures ANOVA. The design ends up being a 3 x 2 x 7, with phase of experiment (3 levels), type of image (2 levels) and affective state endorsement (7 levels).

What has me worried is that a number of the response items contain skewed data (confirmed by Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Shapiro-Wilk). For example, responses to the word "sad" tended to cluster at the low end of the likert scale (good for the participants, bad for me).

I usually collect accuracy or reaction time data which tends to not be as skewed (or even normally distributed), so I'm a little out of my depth here. Square root and log transformations don't fix the issue, and I'm worried that the lack of normality in my data may make the results less robust.

Any suggestions/ideas on how to best deal with skewed data?

Comment: What about multinomial regression? Seems to be a better fit since the response is categorical and not continuous.

Comment: Thanks @bdeonovic, I had thought of and will have to look into multinomial regression. I was shying away from it because likert scales are treated as continuous (as long as the underlying concept being measured is continuous).

Comment: With likert data you could look into ordinal logit regression